# Coloring Text in string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

How can I color that string in code

```
private void HandleChatSpam()
{
    PlayerScript playerScript = PlayerScript.FromPhoton(PhotonNetwork.player);
    playerScript.ChatMessage("mpgh.net - BlackBoom pub build");
}
```

How can I color text in line here `ChatMessage("mpgh.net - BlackBoom pub build");` text that I want to color (green) is `mpgh.net - BlackBoom pub build`

I already tried:

```
playerScript.ChatMessage(Color.green, "mpgh.net - BlackBoom pub build");
```

But I get this error

> no overload for method 'ChatMessage' takes 2 arguments

What is ChatMessage

```
private void ChatMessage(string)
```

it's in reference

Comment: What version of unity are you using? Is it unity5 if so just grab the text object and change the color property

Comment: Uh...is `ChatMessage()` a method from Photon? If that's the case, then you probably are stuck with what you've got. In that case, I recommend displaying this in a text field set to display Rich Text and working the colour in to the content you're sending.

Comment: Check this maybe it can help: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/592242/changing-color-of-a-string-1.html

Comment: it's method from photon

Answer (score 2):

You can use Unity [Rich Text](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StyledText.html) to color a string or parts of it.

In your case it would be :

```
playerScript.ChatMessage("<color=green>mpgh.net - BlackBoom pub build</color>");
```

Comment: `ChatMessage` is not part of the UI, so how is this going to work ?

Comment: Well we don't really know what his ChatMessage does so it's hard to tell.

Comment: `ChatMessage` sends message to photon server (in game chat)